# Android - How to get wifi SNR (Signal-to-Noise Ratio)?

Tags: android, android-wifi

Is there any API to get the **android WiFi SNR**? From my searches so far there's only CellNetwork and GPSSatellite SNR.

Comment: FYI I don't think the framework exposes this much low level information to you.

Comment: Is it just an opinion or fact?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's a fact, since the hardware doesn't reveal this to you (fairly certain).  The system communicates with the modem through the RIL, which I don't think exposes this.  Though because I haven't read the RIL docs recently I'm not confident enough to post this as an answer.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I'll keep this question open for a while in case some might have a solution. Thanks @KristopherMicinski. :>

Answer (score 8):

The basic answer to this question is that you cannot get it via the Android API.  You might be able to do it for individual chips by modifying the Android firmware or hooking into a device specific driver.  However, you should be aware that most wifi cards do *not report* SNR!  [(link..)](http://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/linux/sa/wifi_signal_quality) As such, there is certainly no way to obtain SNR through the Android SDK classes, and there may not be any way even if you do have the ability to modify the firmware (you don't, for all practical purposes).  I dug through all of the Android SDK specific `android.net.wifi` sources and didn't find anything supporting this.